# CSS selector which takes all label.control-label except from form with class .floating-labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this piece of code:

```
label.control-label{
    font-weight: bold;
}
label.control-label::after{
    content: ":";
}
```

Which makes [Bootswatch Paper's](https://bootswatch.com/paper/) labels for input bold and adds `:` after label, and it works very well. Then I found a way to create floating label: [Paper description and example of floating labels](http://news.bootswatch.com/post/110161099627/material-design-in-bootstrap-with-paper) and, to prevent behavior change in other forms, I add class `.floating-labels` to one of form and created this CSS:

```
/* Based on Ryan Walters solution http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/z9ymd852/ 

*/

/* --- material floating label --- */

form.floating-labels .form-group {
    display: flex;
    height: 55px;
}

form.floating-labels .control-label {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(0, 22px, 0) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 240ms;
}

form.floating-labels .form-group.focused .control-label {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.75);
}

form.floating-labels .form-control {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

form.floating-labels .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
    transition: 240ms;
}

form.floating-labels .form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    transition: none;
}

form.floating-labels .form-group.focused .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #bbb;
}
```

And it also works and doens't make mess with forms without `.floating-labels` class, except one mistake - `:` is also added to floating labels, which looks a little bit weird. So i want to create CSS selector which takes all `label.control-label` whithout these allocated in `form` with class`.floating-labels`. I created this CSS, but solution is **not working**:

```
label.control-label:not(form.floating-labels label.control-label){
    font-weight: bold;
}
label.control-label:not(form.floating-labels label.control-label)::after {
    content: ":";
}
```

I will be very happy if anybody helps me to achieve CSS selector, which will take all `label.control-label` except these inside `form` with class `.floating-labels` - thank you in advance.
Code snippet:

```css
label.control-label:not(form.floating-labels label.control-label){
  font-weight: bold;
}

label.control-label:not(form.floating-labels label.control-label)::after{
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class='control-label'>Should has ':' and be bold</label>
    <input>
 </form>
<form class='floating-labels'>
  <label class='control-label'>Should NOT be bold</label>
    <input>
 </form>
```

**Solution**, based on @Diego López's answer:

```
form:not(.floating-labels) label.control-label{
    font-weight: bold;
}
form:not(.floating-labels) label.control-label::after{
    content: ":";
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, You want to select all the labels with class `.control-label` and avoid labels inside `form` with class `.floating-labels` ?

Comment: @Joker not exactly - I want to select all labels with class `.control-labels` and avoid labels in `form` tag with class `floating-labels`. **EDIT**: exactly, that's my target :)

Comment: You need to create a fiddle for your code in order to get a better and working solution here.

Comment: Haven't you simply tried 
    `form.floating-labels label.control-label::after { content: ""; }`
?

Comment: @Joker I created snippet

Comment: @G-Host If I can't find a "one-line" solution, I definetely do it with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `>` selector for with the `:not()` you are already using

```
form:not(.floating-labels) > label.control-label{
  font-weight: bold;
}

form:not(.floating-labels) > label.control-label::after{
  content: ":";
}
```

Comment: Based on your solution (because real code is a little bit more complicated as snippet which I provided) I build working solution, thanks for help :)

Comment: my pleasure, have a nice coding

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following CSS to do it.

```
form.floating-labels label.control-label {
    font-weight: normal;
}
form.floating-labels label.control-label::after {
    content:"";
}
```

---

Here below is a working snippet.

```css
label.control-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
label.control-label::after {
  content: ":";
}
form.floating-labels label.control-label {
  font-weight: normal;
}
form.floating-labels label.control-label::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class='control-label'>Should has ':' and be bold</label>
  <input>
</form>
<form class='floating-labels'>
  <label class='control-label'>Should NOT be bold</label>
  <input>
</form>
```